# Cannot redeclare class grocery_CRUD_Model_Driver

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

good day

The problem started when grocery update the version to version 1.5.1 crud in my system developed in `codeigniter 2.1.3`

When I want to call the grocery crud in the system jumps me this message

> Fatal error: Can not redeclare class grocery_CRUD_Model_Driver /home/fi000273/public_html/chequecupon/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php online in 1492

Anyone know what might be happening?

Thank you very much!
Bruno

Comment: `Can not redeclare class` error means same class is including more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are redeclaring the same class twice.  Maybe including it twice, or including two different things that include it.

I would check in the file
`/home/fi000273/public_html/chequecupon/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php` on line 1492.

Comment: Thanks for the help
I've seen and not declared twice the same class

on line 474 declares
grocery_CRUD_Model_Driver class extends grocery_CRUD_Field_Types

and then in 1522 it appears again

grocery_CRUD_Layout class extends grocery_CRUD_Model_Driver

thank you very much